# 1-px distance between a div and its vertical scrollbar, making visible the coloured background

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

If you run the following code snippet in Full page (Run > Full page), you'll see a vertical red 1-pixel border near the vertical scrollbar, in Chrome / Windows. Why?

[image]

I've found workarounds (see Note2 below), so my goal is not only to avoid it, but to understand the reason for this red border.  *There normally should be no distance between div `#popup` and its scrollbar* (or am I wrong?) **Why is this border there?**

```css
body, html { height: 100%; width: 100%; }
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#popup { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 10%; width: 80%; height: 100%; background-color: white; z-index: 10; overflow-y: auto; outline: 0; }
#popupmain { height: 100%; width: 100%; font-size: 0.9em; padding: 5%; box-sizing: border-box; outline: 0; border: 0; }
#popupclose { top: 5px; right: 5px; position: fixed; cursor: pointer; color: white; }
#popupdarkbg { position: fixed; z-index: 5; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; background-color: red;  }
```

```html
<div id="popup">
  <div id="popupmain">
    <p id="popuplongdescription">a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a</p>
  </div>
  <div id="popupclose">X</div>  
</div>
<div id="popupdarkbg"></div>
```

Note: the `#popupdarkbg` div is normally black, with some opacity: `background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.75);`, and the `#popup` (by default: hidden) is normally triggered/opened by a click on a link, with Javascript. I removed this part here to show only the core problem in this minimal example.

Note2: a solution to remove this border is to remove the `#popupclose` div or to move it out of `#popup` div. It works, but why?

Comment: maybe sime sub-pixel and rounding calculation ... i saw a similar question to this, will try to find it

Comment: @TemaniAfif On a mobile, maybe, but I'm on a desktop computer, with standard pixel density (no sub pixel things usually?).